# The onTouchEvent's event.getY() method of the main Android activity returns a value that is shifted compared to the actual screen position

Tags: android

I have a problem with the behvaior of Android's `onTouchEvent`:

When I start my application, I set the main activity's window's system UI visibility flags to `FULLSCREEN` and `IMMERSIVE`, and so with the view passed to `setContentView`, and right after those operation everything seems to work fine.

However, when I drop down the drop-down menu of the Android system and then hide it away, the values returned by the touch event's `getY` method are shifted by 60 (which is - as I presume - the height of my phone's status bar)

I managed to capture this behavior on a video:

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/SY_KoDVtUHc

Is there any way to force the `getY` method to always return values in the screen's coordinate system?

If you want to have a look at the source of my app, you can find the definition of the main Activity class here:

https://github.com/panicz/grasp/blob/main/src/grasp-android.scm#L1273

(the app is written in a fairly little known JVM language called Kawa, which is a dialect of the Scheme programming language, but I think it should be fairly straightforward to analyze to the majority of experienced Java/Kotlin developers)

Answer (score 0):

After a few weeks of struggle, I finally found solution. The trick was to subtract - from the value obtained by calling touch event's `getY()` method - the value of the view's parent's (obtained by calling view's `getParent()` method) top position (obtained by calling view's `getTop()` method).

I'm not sure to what extent the solution is robust, but it seems to have solved my problem.